# How to use forEach in Firebase Cloud Functions while querying?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

So, I have a https function, which when triggered, needs to read the current server time and get the list of items that have a target_date which is lesser than the current time. Once it gets those list of items, those respective items need to be updated by setting its 'status' value to 'completed'. I have written the function but it is throwing an error. Can you please help me fix it?

```
exports.checkCampaignDate = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

  const current_time = Date.now();
  console.log("current time", current_time);

  var targetRef = admin.database().ref('/Fund');
    console.log("target ref", targetRef);

  targetRef.orderByChild("time_left").endAt(current_time).once("value", function(snapshot) {
    const artcall_list = snapshot.val();
    const artcall_id = snapshot.key;

    snapshot.forEach((artcallSnap) => {
        console.log("Artcall Snap", artcallSnap.val());
        artcallSnap.child("status").set("completed");
     });   

    console.log("This is the list of artcalls that have this same date", artcall_list);
    console.log("This is the artcall id:", artcall_id);
  // do some stuff once
});

return null;

});
```

My database:

```
  "Fund" : {
    "-LEEy7uxXEeI4AJuePoB" : {
      "amount_funded" : 5200,
      "artist_name" : "Sean Roldan and Friends",
      "genre" : "Indian Blues and Jazz",
      "image_url" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/artcall-f8f1a.appspot.com/o/profile_images%2Fthumbs%2Fseanroldan.jpg?alt=media&token=6414d8d6-e8a8-487e-baf3-0d36d017a205",
      "percent_funded" : 0.29714285714285715,
      "perf_location" : "Chennai",
      "reward_amt" : 6000,
      "target_amount" : 1750000,
      "target_date" : 1566568176731,
      "time_left" : 1566568176731,
      "total_backers" : 1
      "status" : "incomplete"
    },
    "-asdffdsa123" : {
      "amount_funded" : 0,
      "artist_name" : "Agam",
      "genre" : "Rock",
      "image_url" : "default",
      "percent_funded" : 0,
      "perf_location" : "Chennai",
      "target_amount" : 1300000,
      "target_amt" : 1300000,
      "target_date" : 1566568176731,
      "time_left" : 1566568176731,
      "total_backers" : 0
      "status" : "incomplete"
    }
  },
```

Error:

```
TypeError: artcallSnap.child(...).set is not a function
    at snapshot.forEach (/user_code/index.js:311:36)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:4255:20
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:3669:24
    at LLRBNode.inorderTraversal (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:2606:13)
    at SortedMap.inorderTraversal (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:3052:27)
    at ChildrenNode.forEachChild (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:3668:24)
    at DataSnapshot.forEach (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:4254:31)
    at /user_code/index.js:309:12
    at onceCallback (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:4843:51)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:4465:22
    at exceptionGuard (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:691:9)
    at EventList.raise (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:9727:17)
    at EventQueue.raiseQueuedEventsMatchingPredicate_ (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:9681:41)
    at EventQueue.raiseEventsForChangedPath (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:9665:14)
    at Repo.onDataUpdate_ (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:12770:26)
    at PersistentConnection.onDataPush_ (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:12070:18)
    at PersistentConnection.onDataMessage_ (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:12064:18)
    at Connection.onDataMessage_ (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:11341:14)
    at Connection.onPrimaryMessageReceived_ (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:11335:18)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:11236:27)
    at WebSocketConnection.appendFrame_ (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:10841:18)
    at WebSocketConnection.handleIncomingFrame (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:10891:22)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`artcallSnap` is a [`DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot), which doesn't have a `set()` method. To get the [`Reference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference) from a snapshot, use its `ref` property. So:

```
artcallSnap.ref.child("status").set("completed")
```